# curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'www.opscode.com'

Tags: curl, chef-infra, knife-solo

I've something wrong after do the knife solo prepare. 
I dont know why this happen.

```
$ knife solo prepare root@url  -c solo.rb -i /../path/certificate.pem
Bootstrapping Chef...
Enter the password for root@url:
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'www.opscode.com'
bash: install.sh: No such file or directory
Generating node config './nodes/url.json'...
```

i'm manualy create .pem by following this step.
http://panoptic.com/wiki/aolserver/How_to_generate_self-signed_SSL_certificates

what is wrong with curl?

**cmiiw**

Answer (score 2):

Curl is unable to reach DNS server to convert human readable domain name to IP. Check your /etc/resolv.conf entries in case of linux. You should be able to reach atleast one server in that file.

Comment: so there's no something wrong with my .pem file? @jagadesshwaran-k

Comment: No, there is something wrong with your `/etc/resolv.conf` on the bootstrapped host.